# What would be the appropriate account for written off loans to friends and family?

Tags: accounting, double-entry, bookkeeping

In the past I have lent some money to friends and family, which I have not gotten back. I don't want to ask them for the cash, but I do want to clean up my accounts.

How would I record this in my books?

Currently I have loans to friends and family in separate asset accounts, which I call "`asset.<person's full name>`".

FYI:

1. I think I get the basic principle of accrual accounting, but I am not familiar with standard terminology for standard accounts.
2. I am self-learning accounting to help me manage my personal finances, and manage my small businesses.

Comment: For tax purposes, or for accounting purposes?

Comment: Are you forgiving the debts? or just charging them off?

Comment: Do you actually prepare a personal "Balance Sheet" / "Financial statements"? To what end?

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon the obvious end of OP seeing where she(?) stands financially.

Answer (score 7):

A simple way to account debt forgiveness of your receivables is to utilize a "**Bad Debt**" expense account. Take the following two examples:

1. *You loan $500 to Aaron with no interest accrued through its life.*

   - Debit the **Bad Debt** expense account for $500.
   - Credit the **Aaron** receivable asset account for $500.
2. *You loan $10000 to Barbara with $300 interest accrued.*

   - Debit the **Bad Debt** expense account for $10300.
   - Credit the **Barbara** receivable asset account for $10000.
   - Credit the **Interest** receivable asset account for $300.

If you are only forgiving a portion of the principal, another popular term used is [**Principal Reduction**](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/principal-reduction.asp) as the expense account.